# How to make table responsive using css?

Tags: css, responsive

I need help making this page work.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH0yi.png)

Use the `@media screen and (max-width: 750px)` as the place for the CSS code needed at the smaller screen size. Watch the video provided with this lesson to assist with this task.

- Use the provided external CSS file.
- Use the Google Fonts provided in the link.
- Main text is: font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
- Heading is: font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
- Do not add any IDs or Classes to the HTML page.
- Code will need to be added to make the table, table headings, and its related data, appear
  properly at the smaller screen size.
- Use only the following units: vw, vh, %, rem and em

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bike Trails</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Permanent+Marker&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cabin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>

<body>
        <header>
            <h1> Wisconsin Bike Trails </h1>
        </header>

        <section>


            <table>
                <caption>A dollar sign ($) indicates that bikers age 16 and older must have a state trail pass.</caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Park, Forest or Trail Name</th>
                        <th>Miles</th>
                        <th>Fee</th>
                        <th>Surface</th>
                        <th>Electric bicycles </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>400 State Trail</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone (7.5 miles have parallel horse trail)</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ahnapee State Trail</td>
                    <td>46</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Badger State Trail</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt 6 miles, limestone 34 miles</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Bearskin State Trail</td>
                    <td>18.3</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Granite</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Capital City State Trail</td>
                    <td> 10 </td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Chippewa River State Trail</td>
                    <td>26</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt 10 miles, seal coat 10 miles</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Elroy-Sparta State Trail</td>
                    <td>32.5</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Fox River State Trail</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt 5.4 miles, limestone 8.6 miles</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Gandy Dancer State Trail</td>
                    <td>47.3</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Glacial Drumlin State Trail</td>
                    <td>52</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt 7.5 miles, limestone 41.5 miles</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Great Sauk State Trail</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Great River State Trail</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Green Circle State Trail</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>-- </td>
                    <td>Asphalt and granite</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hank Aaron State Trail</td>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>-- </td>
                    <td>Asphalt</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Hillsboro State Trail</td>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kettle Moraine State Forest - Northern Unit<br />
                        Lake to Lake Bike Trail</td>
                    <td>6.5 </td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>La Crosse River State Trail</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                    <td> $</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mascoutin Valley State Trail </td>
                    <td>19</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>Varies</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Military Ridge State Trail</td>
                    <td>40</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt 3 miles, limestone 38 miles</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mound View State Trail</td>
                    <td>7</td>
                    <td>--</td>
                    <td>Asphalt</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mountain-Bay State Trail</td>
                    <td>89</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Oconto River State Trail </td>
                    <td>8</td>
                    <td>-- </td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Old Abe State Trail</td>
                    <td>20</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Peninsula State Park<br />
                        Sunset Bike Trail</td>
                    <td>9</td>
                    <td>-- </td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Point Beach State Forest<br />
                        Rawley Point Bike Trail</td>
                    <td>5 (links to 8 miles outside forest)</td>
                    <td>-- </td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>No</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Red Cedar State Trail</td>
                    <td>14.5</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Stower Seven Lakes State Trail</td>
                    <td>14</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Sugar River State Trail</td>
                    <td>23.5</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Asphalt 1 mile, limestone 22.5 miles</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tomorrow River State Trail</td>
                    <td>18</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>White River State Trail</td>
                    <td>11</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wild Goose State Trail</td>
                    <td>32</td>
                    <td>-- </td>
                    <td>Limestone (4.1 miles have parallel horse trail)</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Wiouwash State Trail</td>
                    <td>35</td>
                    <td>$</td>
                    <td>Limestone</td>
                    <td>Yes</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">Data source: https://dnr.wi.gov/topic/parks/activities/bike.html</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </section>
        <footer>
            <img src="images/cycling_bikes_lg3.png" alt="" />
            <p><small>&copy; 20xx - (Add your name.) </small></p>
            <p><small>Image source: https://www.clipart.email/download/2257249.html</small></p>
        </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. Because I don't see any CSS in your code.

Comment: Please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) and  [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-meta-element) tags do not use and do not need a closing slash and never have in any HTML specification.

Comment: I am lost because I am sad that it's so cold outside.

Answer (score 0):

try below code, hope this helps

1. use media screen
2. catch nth child of tr

```css
    @media only screen and (max-width: 760px), (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
            display: block;
        }
        thead tr {
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }
        tr {
          margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
        }
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
          background: #ccc;
        }
        td {
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%;
        }
        td:before {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%;
            padding-right: 10px;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
        td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "First Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Last Name"; }
        td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "title"; }
        td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Color"; }
        td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "address?"; }
        td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Secret Alias"; }
        td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Date of Birth"; }
        td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "City"; }
        td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "number"; }
        td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "other Data"; }
    }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<table role="table">
  <thead role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <th role="columnheader">First Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Last Name</th>
      <th role="columnheader">title</th>
      <th role="columnheader"> Color</th>
      <th role="columnheader">number</th>
      <th role="columnheader">address</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Date of Birth</th>
      <th role="columnheader">City</th>
      <th role="columnheader">area</th>
      <th role="columnheader">Data</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody role="rowgroup">
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">James</td>
      <td role="cell">Matman</td>
      <td role="cell">Chief Sandwich Eater</td>
      <td role="cell">Lettuce Green</td>
      <td role="cell">Trek</td>
      <td role="cell">Digby Green</td>
      <td role="cell">January 13, 1979</td>
      <td role="cell">Gotham City</td>
      <td role="cell">3.1</td>
      <td role="cell">RBX-12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row">
      <td role="cell">The</td>
      <td role="cell">Tick</td>
      <td role="cell">Crimefighter Sorta</td>
      <td role="cell">Blue</td>
      <td role="cell">Wars</td>
      <td role="cell">John Smith</td>
      <td role="cell">July 19, 1968</td>
      <td role="cell">Athens</td>
      <td role="cell">N/A</td>
      <td role="cell">Edlund, Ben (July 1996).</td>
    </tr>
     
  </tbody>
</table>
```